# on Vue, how to use a function from a component in another component?

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue.js, vue-component, logout

I have this component, with the function "logout" like below:

```
// @/component/Painel.vue
<template></template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'panel',
  methods: {
    logout: function () {
      this.$session.destroy()
      this.$router.push('/')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I need to use the function "logout" defined in Painel.vue in the Navbar.vue, like below:

```
// @/component/Navbar.vue
<template>
<div class="navbar">
    <a @click="logout" class="nav-link m-2 my-2 my-md-0" >Sair</a>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'navbar'
}
</script>
```

I've tried to import the component and use the function like this, but didnt work

```
import Painel from '@/components/authentication/Painel.vue'
...
this.logout()
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. Which you should use depends on how the function needs to be called.

**Option 1.** (Plugin) If either component needs to call the `logout` function programmatically, rather than just containing a button for the strict purpose of logging out. For example, if one component contains a button like "Submit and Logout" then `logout` is additional functionality and needs to be called programmatically.

In this case, you should refactor `logout` into a separate [plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html), which are used as a way to provide globally-scoped functionality or other attributes in Vue.

An example:

```
const LogoutPlugin {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.prototype.$logout = function() {
            // logout logic
        }
    }
}

Vue.use(LogoutPlugin);

new Vue({
   // ... options
})
```

Then `logout` can be called with `this.$logout()`.

**Option 2.** (Composition) If both components just need to have logout buttons, then you can accomplish this by creating a `LogoutButton` Component that you place inside of both components.

Example:

```
<template>
    <button @click="logout">Log Out</button>
</template

<script>
export default {
    name: "LogoutButton",
    methods: {
        logout() {
            // logout logic
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Then place a `LogoutButton` in any component that needs it. Like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="navbar">
        <LogoutButton/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import LogoutButton from './LogoutButton.vue';

export default {
    name: "NavBar",
    components: {
        LogoutButton
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create EventBus for communication between components.

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.prorotype.$bus = new Vue()

//app init
</script>
```

After define method `logout` in your root component, for example App.vue. And add event listener in `mounted`

```
<script>
export default {
    mounted () {
        this.$bus.$on('logout', () => this.logout())
    },
    methods: {
        logout () {
            this.$session.destroy()
            this.$router.push('/')
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

then in any component you can emit `logout` event with `this.$bus.$emit('logout')`

links:
[creating event bus](https://medium.com/vuejobs/create-a-global-event-bus-in-vue-js-838a5d9ab03a)